# Documentation for xsession

Tags: documentation, kiosk

Where I can find info about Xsessions?
documents, blogs, anything is ok.
My project is about boot in kiosk mode, and I need it.
thanks for your help!

Comment: List questions are usually frowned-upon. See the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from reading manual page ([man Xsession](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/Xsession.5.html)).

Answer (score 0):

A kiosk mode is running an X session where anything that can be disabled witout problems is disabled - But not more.

That's the perfect case where it makes sense to just jump into the code itself to learn:

It's a collection of scripts, most simple, connected in a simple way,
and you need to find you way throught the code anyway to build the kiosk mode.

Take a look at `/etc/X11/Xsession` - it runs the separate scripts in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` at the end in their order, if they are not marked as disabled by a name change to indicate that. Then just got through all the scripts:
Many are trivial stubs, basically empty. Some are complicated - but not relevant to your use case. So there will noy that much code be left you really need to read.

```
$ ls -l1 /etc/X11/Xsession  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3730 Mar 22  2012 /etc/X11/Xsession
$ ls -1 /etc/X11/Xsession.d
00upstart
20desktop-profiles_activateDesktopProfiles
20x11-common_process-args
30x11-common_xresources
35x11-common_xhost-local
40x11-common_xsessionrc
50x11-common_determine-startup
52load-gtk-vector-screenshot-gtk-module
55gnome-session_gnomerc
55numlockx
55xfce4-session
60imwheel_start-imwheel
60x11-common_localhost
60x11-common_xdg_path
60xbrlapi
60xdg-user-dirs-update
65compiz_profile-on-session
70gconfd_path-on-session
70im-config_launch
75dbus_dbus-launch
80appmenu
80appmenu-gtk3
80im-switch
80kubuntu-xmodmap
81overlay-scrollbar
90consolekit
90gpg-agent
90qt-a11y
90unclutter
90x11-common_ssh-agent
99upstart
99x11-common_start
```